# How to highlight the differences between subsequent lines in a file?

Tags: linux, logging, formatting, diff

I do a lot of urgent analysis of large logfile analysis. Often this will require tailing a log and looking for changes.

I'm keen to have a solution that will highlight these changes to make it easier for the eye to track.

I have investigated tools and there doesn't appear to be anything out there that does what I am looking for. I've written some scripts in Perl that do it roughly, but I would like a more complete solution.

Can anyone recommend a tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Python script for this purpose that utilizes [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from itertools import tee
from sys import stdin

def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...

    https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def color(c, s):
  """Wrap string s in color c.

  Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/287944/1916449
  """
  try:
    lookup = {'r':'\033[91m', 'g':'\033[92m', 'b':'\033[1m'}
    return lookup[c] + str(s) + '\033[0m'
  except KeyError:
    return s

def diff(a, b):
  """Returns a list of paired and colored differences between a and b."""
  for tag, i, j, k, l in SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).get_opcodes():
    if tag == 'equal': yield 2 * [color('w', a[i:j])]
    if tag in ('delete', 'replace'): yield color('r', a[i:j]), ''
    if tag in ('insert', 'replace'): yield '', color('g', b[k:l])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for a, b in pairwise(stdin):
    print(*map(''.join, zip(*diff(a, b))), sep='')
```

Example `input.txt`:

```
108  finished   /tmp/ts-out.5KS8bq   0       435.63/429.00/6.29 ./eval.exe -z 30
107  finished   /tmp/ts-out.z0tKmX   0       456.10/448.36/7.26 ./eval.exe -z 30
110  finished   /tmp/ts-out.wrYCrk   0       0.00/0.00/0.00 tail -n 1
111  finished   /tmp/ts-out.HALY18   0       460.65/456.02/4.47 ./eval.exe -z 30
112  finished   /tmp/ts-out.6hdkH5   0       292.26/272.98/19.12 ./eval.exe -z 1000
113  finished   /tmp/ts-out.eFBgoG   0       837.49/825.82/11.34 ./eval.exe -z 10
```

Output of `cat input.txt | ./linediff.py`:

[image: linediff output]

Answer (score 3):

## Levenshtein distance

Wikipedia:
Levenshtein distance between two strings is minimum number of operations needed to transform one string into the other, where an operation is an insertion, deletion, or substitution of a single character.

```
public static int LevenshteinDistance(char[] s1, char[] s2) {
    int s1p = s1.length, s2p = s2.length;
    int[][] num = new int[s1p + 1][s2p + 1];

    // fill arrays
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1p; i++)
        num[i][0] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i <= s2p; i++)
        num[0][i] = i;

    for (int i = 1; i <= s1p; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= s2p; j++)
            num[i][j] = Math.min(Math.min(num[i - 1][j] + 1,
                    num[i][j - 1] + 1), num[i - 1][j - 1]
                    + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1));

    return num[s1p][s2p];
}
```

## Sample App in Java

String Diff

[image]

Application uses LCS algorithm to concatenate 2 text inputs into 1. Result will contain minimal set of instructions to make one string for the other. Below the instruction concatenated text is displayed.

Download application:
    [String Diff.jar](https://sites.google.com/site/margusmartseppcode/problems/string/StringDiff.jar?attredirects=0)

Download source:
    [Diff.java](https://sites.google.com/site/margusmartseppcode/problems/string/Diff.java?attredirects=0)

Comment: Thanks Magnus, looks like a good algo to know about/add to the list. Might help me roll my own diff highlighting, but ideally would like to find a library/tool such as that in my answer

Comment: Thanks, Im a keen user of this and other diff tools. Ive updated the question wording to give more background..

Answer (score 0):

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

.. this look promising, will update this with more info when Ive played more..